# Counterexample of a space where the wedge product of harmonic forms is not harmonic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, harmonic-functions

In our lecture of Advanced Geometry, we had an example of a manifold on which there exist harmonic forms whose wedge product is not again harmonic. I didn't completely understand the example.

Let $S$ be an oriented, closed surface of genus $g \geq 2$. Then we know that $H_{dR}^{1}(S)= \mathbb{R}^{2g}$.

1. I didn't know that. If anyone has a reference, that would be great.

Now we put some Riemannian metric $g$ on $S$. Let $\omega_1, \omega_2$ be two harmonic 1-forms. Then $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2$ defines a nontrivial element in $H_{dR}^2(S)$. We know that $\omega_1$ is a smooth 1-form, so a smooth section of $T^{*}S$. Since $\chi(S) = 2-2g \neq 0$ we know: $T^{*}(S)$ cannot have a (smooth) section without zero.Thus $\omega_1\wedge \omega_2$ has zeros.

2. I don't understand how that shows that the wedge product is not harmonic. Does the proof somehow use the Hodge theorem ?
3. I don't know why we can't have a smooth nonzero section of $T^{*}S$

Comment: For the first point, we know that the Euler characteristic of a genus $g$ surface is $2-2g$. But it is also $\dim H^0 - \dim H^1 + \dim H^2$. Since the surface is connected, $H^0 \simeq H^1\simeq \Bbb R$, hence $\dim H^1 = 2g$.

Comment: Ahh thank you ! But you mean $H^0 \simeq H^2 \simeq \mathbb{R}$ right ?

Comment: Nonzero Euler characteristic tells you that $TS$ (or $T^*S$) cannot have a nowhere-zero section.

Comment: @PaulJoh Of course!